# Does Orange scale the data automatically for the linear regression with Ridge regularization

Tags: linear-regression, orange, feature-scaling, regularization

I'm using the linear regression tool with the Ridge regularization. To use the Ridge regularization, I have to scale the data first. Does Orange scale the data automatically? I can't find any information about this mentioned in Orange's documentation for Ridge regularization.

In python's `scikit-learn`, I have to scale the data manually before using Ridge Regression. In MATLAB, the scaling in the Ridge function included. So, do I have to scale the data manually before I'm using the Ridge Regression in orange?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not by default, no, as shown by the `normalise=False` [here](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/reference/regression.html#Orange.regression.linear.RidgeRegressionLearner):

> class Orange.regression.linear.RidgeRegressionLearner(alpha=1.0,
>   fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, copy_X=True, max_iter=None,
>   tol=0.001, solver='auto', preprocessors=None)

Comment: I would just like to add that Orange usually wraps scikit-learn's models, so the same that applies for sklean would apply for Orange.